# Communication between sibling user controls in a tab control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

We have a tab control with three tabs. Each tab contains two user controls A and B. User control A contains a data grid. User control B contains a text box and a checked list box to filter the data grid in user control A. What is the best approach to communicate between two user controls in above mentioned scenario?
I am using MVVM and event aggregators of Prism Framework.

My Viem Models are as below for each tab

```
        User Control A  User Control B
Tab1    ViewModelGrid1  ViemModelGridFilter
Tab2    ViewModelGrid2  ViemModelGridFilter
Tab3    ViewModelGrid3  ViemModelGridFilter
```

I want to use one single ViewModel for Grid filtering.

My publish event from ViemModelGridFilter of Tab 1 should only be subscribed by ViewModelGrid1   of Tab 1. But right now its being subscribed by all the three grid view models.

```
this._eventAggregator.GetEvent<GridFilterEvent>().Publish(list);
```

Comment: Through ViewModel?

Comment: Mediator or Messenger maybe? Are you using an MVVM framework?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below demo where I am filtering a collection of students from the text provided in search text box. Datagrid and Textbox, both are in different user controls and share the same data context.

> XAML for Datagrid UserControl:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="studentGrid" CanUserAddRows="False" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Students, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Student's grade" Binding="{Binding StudentGrade}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Student's Name" Binding="{Binding StudentName}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

> XAML for TextBox UserControl:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Height="30" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

> XAML to be placed in tab control:

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:tb></local:tb>
    <local:dg></local:dg>
</StackPanel>
```

> ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   public MainWindowViewModel()
    {            
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        Students.Add(new Student { StudentGrade = 1, StudentName = "Jack" });
        Students.Add(new Student { StudentGrade = 2, StudentName = "Jill" });
        Students.Add(new Student { StudentGrade = 3, StudentName = "Humpty" });
    }

    private string _SearchText;
    //to be used to filer datagrid
    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return _SearchText; }
        set
        {
            _SearchText = value;
            //filter logic, I am filtering on base of student name, you can have your own implementation.
            Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(Students.Where(x => x.StudentName.ToUpper().Contains(value.ToUpper())).ToList());
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SearchText");
        }
    }        

    private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;
    // to hold list of students
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get { return _students; }
        set
        {
            _students = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Students");
        }
    }        

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

}
```

and code to assign DataContext XAML.cs file:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();            
    }
```

This approach is pure MVVM and can be enhanced, modified as per need without much hassle.